# Not validating two dates,Even if both are of date type using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know its too silly to ask this,But am confused y is this not working.Even though every values looks fine in debug mode.

Actually what I want to achieve is to display error if `productionStartFrom` is less than current date.

**Controller**

```
scope.currentDate={};
scope.checkDate=function(productionStartFrom){
          currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy", "UTC");
          console.log(currentDate); //28/04/2017
          console.log(productionStartFrom); //05/04/2017
          if(currentDate > productionStartFrom){
              scope.dateErrMsg="Date cant be less than today";
              alert("Invalid Date");
              scope.myForm.$invalid="true";
          }
          else if(currentDate < productionStartFrom){
              scope.dateErrMsg="";
          }
    }
```

**html page**

```
<datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" selector="form-control">
<input name="productionStartFrom" type="text" ng-model="produce.productionStartFrom"                                                                                  pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/[0-9]{4}"
ng-minlength="10" maxlength="10" x-ng-change="checkDate(produce.productionStartFrom)"                                /> </datepicker>
```

Comment: I guess, the way you are comparing dates causing issue

Comment: Whats wrong with comparison

Comment: make sure productionStartFrom is of date type

Comment: yes its date type only. Its coming from datePicker. so will that effect any

Answer (score 1):

```
scope.currentDate={};
scope.checkDate=function(productionStartFrom){
      currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy", "UTC");
      console.log(currentDate); 
      if(currentDate >= productionStartFrom){
          scope.dateErrMsg="Date cant be less than today";
          alert("Invalid Date");
          scope.myForm.$invalid="true";
      }
      else if(currentDate <= productionStartFrom){
          scope.dateErrMsg="";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like the below code,

```
$scope.checkDate=function(productionStartFrom){
        currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy", "UTC");
        productionStartFrom = $filter('date')(new Date(productionStartFrom), "dd/MM/yyyy", "UTC");
        if(currentDate > productionStartFrom){
            $scope.dateErrMsg="Date cant be less than today";
            console.log("Invalid Date");
        }
        else if(currentDate < productionStartFrom){
            $scope.dateErrMsg="Valid Date";
        }
  }
```

Comment: Please check my plunkr link which is working **(check the console log)**. http://plnkr.co/edit/W9VspRk3fREKJvxjuRcM?p=preview